# Why did the sorcerer/wizard spell lists diverge in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, sorcerer, designer-reasons

The party I am playing with is currently playing *Pathfinder*, and we are considering switching to *5e* within the new couple of weeks. I have been doing research on the difference with *Sorcerers* between *Pathfinder* and *5e*. In *Pathfinder*, *Wizards* and *Sorcerers* utilized the same spell list and could select any spell from the list as they pleased whenever the ability to gain new spells arose.

During my research, I came cross this site [5e Spell List](http://www.5esrd.com/spellcasting/spell-lists#TOC-Sorcerer-Spells). By the looks of it, *Sorcerers* contain a far less variety of spells that the *Wizards* do.

Is there any reason why that is?

e.g. 
  *Sorcerers* cannot use **Grease** or **Alarm** whereas *Wizards* can.

**NOTE:** Answers must cite *documented developer commentary* on this matter. Personal theories on why it is the case need not apply.

Comment: OK, so this is a tricky kind of question to not get closed as subjective here - the short answer is "because the developers designed it that way."  Answers that are your personal opinion on why this contributes to class balance are not good answers.  Direct developer citations of why they made that change are.

Comment: Note that Sorcerers also have some spells that Wizards don't, this isn't a one-way thing.

Comment: [Related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55732/15469).

Comment: Note that "Sorcerer's spell list" == "Wizard's spell list" is *only* true for 3e and its derivatives. In no other edition did two classes share a spell list

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because designer intent questions are off topic.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Mike Mearls stated on Twitter:

> for sorcerer, we avoid more complex spells. Sorcerer magic is simpler, more direct

See: http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/08/22/sorcerer-vs-wizard-spell-list/

The spells you mentioned are more "utility" spells - they have an effect that is not immediate or that can be used in ways that might not seem apparent.  Sorcerers have mainly instant damage magic or spells that have fewer possible uses.

Comment: Basically, Wizards are Fighters (tons of maneuvers and options), while Sorcerers are Barbarians (fewer options, very high raw damage).